# Сравнение в PHP

Tags: php

```
var_export('as1223' == 0); // true ;)
```

Мне одному кажется что это не верно?

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: [http://habrahabr.ru/post/142140/](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142140/).

Про это там в разделе «операторы», пункте «`==` бесполезен.»

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В php много чего нелогичного, если надеяться, что он угадает Ваши мысли. Не сравнивайте переменные разных типов. А если сравниваете, то будьте добры изучить, как именно интерпретатор делает приведение типов.

В данном случае строка преобразовывается к целому, а потом происходит сравенение. Поэтому, к примеру, выражение

```
var_export('1as1223' == 0);
```

уже будет false.

**Вывод**

Всегда вначале приводите типы, если сравниваете разнотипные данные.

Answer (score 3):

Всё верно, при выполнении операции сравнения обе стороны приводятся к единому типу в данном случае int вот и получается (int)"as1223" это 0, поэтому и верно равенство 'as1223' == 0. В то же время 'as1223' == '0' вернет FALSE, так как оба операнда строки.

Comment: '1as122' === 0; //false